# What is my alternative if I don't use UIWebView for ios?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I keep reading it is bad to use UIWebView.  All I currently do is web technologies.  I can program in other languages, but have never used Objective-C.  If I don't wrap my web app in UIWebView, what do I do?  I don't know how to do anything that I'd do in ajax, for example, or parse json on return, etc.

Thanks for any direction.

Comment: I will warn you this: an application that is just a WebView wrapper will get rejected from the AppStore, it has happened to me multiple times.

Comment: so something made in phonegap might get rejected?

Comment: I've never used phone gap, so I can't answer directly for that, but I had a web application that I wanted users to pay for, and thought about using the app store as a purchase method, which got the app rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Starting out, objective-c may seem like a pain compared to other languages. You don't have the same syntax as other languages, strings are handled differently than most languages, and Objects are not strongly-typed.

I suggest, that, starting out, you skip the whole 'retain count' idea and work with ARC, at least for iPhone. ARC is similar to garbage collection in other languages, however, it is not the same in that the compiler adds the deallocation code for you, rather than dynamically deallocating at runtime.

Web-Based things can also be a pain in obj-c, but not so much as in other languages. A good library to use for URL requests is [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) , as it is a good API for connecting to your servers. Other than that, I don't know what else to say, start using the language, dive head in, and don't be afraid to ask here or google if you are stumped!